# How to add a field that changes value dependent on another field in Laravel Nova 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

is there a way to make this scenario work in Laravel Nova 4:

I have a form, where I fill some numeric values using repeater. I would like to add a readonly field inside that form which reactively sums the values of repeater fields.

Thank you!

The problem is that:

1. FormField component does not have access to formData, maybe there is a way to pass it there and watch it?
2. DependsOn with setValue() does not work reactively, only on mount.
3. Maybe there's another way??

Comment: I think you would have to create a new field that takes a list of names and implement your js that finds the field from the name and sums it's value.

Answer (score 0):

If I properly understood you should display the sum of previously added numeric fields. Check [this package](https://novapackages.com/packages/codebykyle/calculated-field), maybe it is obsolete for 4x version of Nova, but you can reuse the main idea
[image]